# NGINX Rewrite return 404

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I Have this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

I tried so in NGINX:
index works fine, others pages return 404 error

```
location /ws_php/modulos/12-projeto-final/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php/?url=$1;
}
```

BUILDING MY URLS
/12-projeto-final/index.php:

```
<?php
        require(REQUIRE_PATH . '/inc/header.inc.php');

        $url = ( isset($_GET['url']) ? strip_tags(trim($_GET['url'])) : 'index');
        $url = explode('/', $url);
        $url[0] = ($url[0] == null ? 'index' : $url[0]);
        $url[1] = ( empty($url[1]) ? null : $url[1]); //EVITA NOCICE

        //var_dump($url);

        if (file_exists(REQUIRE_PATH . '/' . $url[0] . '.php')) :
            require_once(REQUIRE_PATH . '/' . $url[0] . '.php');
        elseif (file_exists(REQUIRE_PATH . '/' . $url[0] . '/' . $url[1] . '.php')) :
            require_once(REQUIRE_PATH . '/' . $url[0] . '/' . $url[1] . '.php');
        else:
            if (file_exists(REQUIRE_PATH . '/404.php')):
                require_once(REQUIRE_PATH . '/404.php');
            else:
                echo "<p style=\"text-align:center; padding:50px 0;\">404 Erro - Arquivo não existe!</p>";
            endif;
        endif;

        require(REQUIRE_PATH . '/inc/footer.inc.php');
        ?>
```

Comment: I think you need not append uri after /index.php, can you detail more what kind of other pages are, other urls?

Comment: wont works too, index: http://cursos.dev/ws_php/modulos/12-projeto-final/, other pages: http://cursos.dev/ws_php/modulos/12-projeto-final/categoria/esportes

Comment: What is your file structure, like for  cursos.dev/ws_php/modulos/12-projeto-final, what should be served, for cursos.dev/ws_php/modulos/12-projeto-final/categoria/esporte‌​s, what should be served?

Comment: got it, /directory/file or /file, urls are stored in database when file is called

Comment: printscreen my dir http://i.imgur.com/JVPOvZW.png

Comment: example /file/<url stored in my database>

Comment: I can see another index.php in cidadeonline folder, i think that is responsible for fetching the data, maybe you need to execute that if that is not already called, so for that change your try_files with, try_files $uri $uri/ /themes/cidadeonline/index.php; or you can change your root as your root might be the theme folder url, in case of any error while doing this chek error log.

Comment: try to correct first thing, that $1 won't have any value, i assume, you want to put data for url argument as request_uri(from apache config), so try ..?url=$request_uri;

Comment: changed, but 404 yet